# Mapping array of object into another array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, mapping, lodash

I want to map this data from a timeseries database:

```
[{
    "time": "2017-05-06T14:51:52.000Z",
    "section": "section-1.1",
    "spot": "mid-mid",
    "moisture": 32.29042774940741,
    "temp": 9.831621647958139,
    "light": 41.63243295916276,
    "tempF": 49.696918966324645
}, {
    "time": "2017-05-06T14:51:53.000Z",
    "section": "section-1.1",
    "spot": "mid-right",
    "moisture": 61.58342622984698,
    "temp": 9.242330770565856,
    "light": 29.846615411317096,
    "tempF": 48.63619538701854
}, {
    "time": "2017-05-06T14:51:55.000Z",
    "section": "section-1.2",
    "spot": "mid-left",
    "moisture": 41.18061223214005,
    "temp": 8.950196176767273,
    "light": 24.003923535345457,
    "tempF": 48.110353118181095
}, {
    "time": "2017-05-06T14:51:57.000Z",
    "section": "section-1.1",
    "spot": "mid-right",
    "moisture": 63.70980718623251,
    "temp": 9.206026133587395,
    "light": 29.120522671747903,
    "tempF": 48.57084704045731
}, {
    "time": "2017-05-06T14:51:57.000Z",
    "section": "section-1.1",
    "spot": "mid-mid",
    "moisture": 30.85714405713664,
    "temp": 9.803760958788422,
    "light": 41.075219175768424,
    "tempF": 49.646769725819155
}]
```

Into this format (pseudo)

```
[{
        "section": "section-1.1",
        "points": [{
            "x": 1241,
            "mid-mid-temp": 1231,
            "mid-left-temp": 1241
        }, {
            "x": 1241,
            "mid-mid-temp": 1231,
            "mid-left-temp": 1241
        }]
    },
    {
        "section": "section-1.2",
        "points": [{
            "x": 1241,
            "mid-right-temp": 1231
        }, {
            "x": 1241,
            "mid-right-temp": 1231
        }]
    }
]
```

Making it possible for graphing different measurements divided by sections and spots. Any ideas how to lodash this?

I only need to take each measurement to plot them into a graph. I don't need all 3 measurements.

Comment: from where are you getting the value of `points` key?

Comment: "x" is static, but should contain the running values of the "time" in the first object. But only for the specific section and spot. "mid-mid-temp" and "mid-left-temp" is a key generated by spot value of each section.

I can easily map points for each spot per section. But cant seem to find a way to include each spot per section.